# How to setup loginurl in angular 6 to work with asp.netcore 2.1 using the new Identity.UI

Tags: angular6, identityserver4, asp.net-core-2.1

How do I get my login url to change from `...../Account/Login` to the `..../Identity/Account/Login` in my angular app?
My Client is an angular 6 app and I am using `angular-auth-oidc-client`.

Thanks

Comment: What did you find with your favorite search engine? [edit] your question and post your code! What happened when you tried it? What did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? Did you already take the [tour]?

Answer (score 1):

when you are calling AddIdentityServer call it like

```
services.AddIdentityServer(SetupIdentityServer)
```

and use this static method.

```
private static void SetupIdentityServer(IdentityServerOptions identityServerOptions)
    {
        identityServerOptions.UserInteraction.LoginUrl = "/Identity/Account/Login";
    }
```